# Minimum and Maximum Number of Tuples

Tags: relational-algebra

Consider Relations R and S where are R is having m tuples and S is having n tuples . m<=n . What would be the minimum and maximum number of tuples in each of the following cases (Assume that nothing is mentioned about key constraints)

1. R union S
2. R intersection S
3. R-S
4. S-R
5. R NATURAL JOIN S
6. R Left OUTER Join S
7. R/S

**My Work**

1. R UNION S

max : n+m ( union we add all the tuples from both relations)

min: 0 ( taking m=n=null )

2. R INTERSECTION S

max : m ( m < n both relation contains same keys then we may get maximum m keys )

min: 0 ( taking m=n=null if no common keys in both relations)

3. R - S

max : m ( if they are disjoint then in R-S we will get all tuples of R )

min: 0 ( if all tuples in R is also present in S)

4. S-R

max : n ( as explained above )

min: 0 ( as explained above )

5. R natural join S

max : n*m ( if no matching key constraints natural join will produce Cartesian product )

min: m ( m < n  when key constraints are taken into consideration )

6. R LEFT OUTER JOIN S

max : m ( everything from left table will be output even if no match)

min: 0 ( when m=0 )

7. R/S

max : m ( when n=0 )

min: *Im Not able to make a  conclusion*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your answers are mostly right, except a few mistakes:

**1. `R UNION S`**

- max : n+m ( union we add all the tuples from both relations)
  **Correct**, when R and S have no common tuple.
- min: 0 ( taking m=n=null )
  **Wrong,** the minimum is `n` (the greatest of the two sizes, m and n). When all the tuples of R also exist in S.
  And m and n cannot be null, they are the sizes of the relations, they are numbers (integers).

**2. `R INTERSECTION S`**

- max : m ( `m<n` both relation contains same keys then we may get maximum m keys )
  **Correct but the reasoning is wrong**. You compare **tuples** of the two relations, not keys.
- min: 0 ( taking m=n=null if no common keys in both relations)
  **Correct but the reasoning is wrong**. The result can be 0 because the two relations may have no common **tuples**).

**3. `R - S`**

- max : m ( if they are disjoint then in R-S we will get all tuples of R )
  **Correct**
- min: 0 ( if all tuples in R is also present in S)
  **Correct**

**4. `S - R`**

- max : n ( as explained above )
  **Correct**
- min: 0 ( as explained above )
  **Wrong,** the minimum is `n - m`.

**5. `R natural join S`**

- max : n*m ( if no matching key constraints natural join will produce Cartesian product )
  **Correct**
- min: m ( m < n  when key constraints are taken into consideration )
  **Wrong,** the minimum is `0`. You can easily find an example, identical with case 2 (`INTERSECTION`).

**6. `R LEFT OUTER JOIN S`**

- max : m ( everything from left table will be output even if no match)
  **Wrong,** the maximum is `m * n`, the same as for natural join. Or just take `ON TRUE`.
- min: 0 ( when m=0 )
  **Wrong**, the minimum is `m`. Example can be the same as for `NATURAL` join above (or just take `ON FALSE`) but it cannot give as a result lees than the number of tuples in `R` (the left relation in the join).

**7. `R / S`**

- max : m ( when n=0 )
  **Correct** but it doesn't have to be n=0 or m=0. You can find another example.
- min: *I'm not able to make a conclusion*.
  **Minimum is `0`** Consider that relational division is similar to integer division. `3 / 7` gives `0` in integer division for example. Try to convert this into relational division.

Answer (score 1):

I have recompiled the above answer more lucidly and added some more relational algebra operations. Hope, it's useful :)

Consider Relations R and S where R is having m tuples and S is having n tuples. m<=n . What would be the minimum and maximum number of tuples in each of the following cases (Assume that nothing is mentioned about key constraints)

1. R union S
2. R intersection S
3. R-S
4. S-R
5. R NATURAL JOIN S
6. R Left OUTER Join S
7. R/S
8. R CROSS PRODUCT S
9. R Right OUTER Join S
10. R Full OUTER Join S

---

These results have been determined considering generic tables without any given candidate keys involved.

Note: if candidate keys for a given table are given, then results will be different.

**1. `R UNION S`**

- max : n+m

Reason : union we add all the tuples from both relations. i.e. When R and S have no common tuple.

- min: n

Reason : The minimum is `n` (the greatest of the two sizes, m and n). When all the tuples of R also exist in S.

---

**2. `R INTERSECTION S`**

- max : m ( `m<n` )

Reason : both relation contains same tuples then we may get maximum m keys

- min: 0

Reason :  if no common tuples in both relations

---

**3. `R - S`**

- max : m

Reason : if they are disjoint (if they have no element in common) then in R-S we will get all tuples of R

- min: 0

Reason : if all tuples in R is also present in S

---

**4. `S - R`**

- max : n

Reason : if they are disjoint (if they have no element in common) then in S-R we will get all tuples of S

- min: n-m

Reason : m<n there will be some tuples in S after deleting the common tuples

---

**5. `R natural join S`**

- max : n*m

Reason : if no matching key constraints, natural join will produce Cartesian product

- min: 0

Reason : Identical with case 2 (`INTERSECTION`).

---

**6. `R LEFT OUTER JOIN S`**

- max : m*n

Reason : if all rows in left table matches with all rows in right table

- min: m (including every tuple from the left table)

Reason : if no tuple matches between the two table, but still we have to include all the tuples from the left table.

The minimum is 1 when m=1 *,* minimum is 2 when m=2, minimum is 0 when m=0

---

**7. `R / S`**

- max : m

Reason : when n=0

- min: 0

Reason : Consider that relational division is similar to integer division. `3 / 7` gives 0 in integer division for example. Try to convert this into relational division

---

**8. `R CROSS PRODUCT S`**

- max & min : m*n

Reason :  combining each row in R with each row in S.

---

**9. `R RIGHT OUTER JOIN S`**

- max : m*n

Reason : if all rows in left table matches with all rows in right table

- min: n (including every tuple from the right table)

Reason : if no tuple matches between the two table, but still we have to include all the tuples from the right table.

The minimum is 1 when n=1 *,* minimum is 2 when n=2, minimum is 0 when n=0

---

**10. `R FULL OUTER JOIN S`**

- max : m*n

Reason : if all rows in left table matches with all rows in right table

- **Case 1→** min: m+n

Reason : if no tuple matches between the two table, but still we have to include all the tuples from the left & right table.

- **Case 2 →** min: max(m,n)

Reason : when every tuple in one of the table matches with tuples in other table.

**elaborate explanation for min: max(m,n) for Full Outer Join:**

Consider relation R with 4 tuples and S with 8 tuples.

So,  min of outer join would be if there's no match. i.e m+n = 4+8 = 12 tuples.

but this is not the case to get absolute minimum.

To get min. in full outer join:

Consider, 4 out of 4 tuples in R matches with S's tuples (4 out 8 is same as R)

this time, resultant relation would have: 4(matched) + 4(unmatched) tuple = 8 tuples. (which is less than 12)